# How to check if a certificate is installed

Tags: c#, certificate

I just started with .NET and C#. I am trying to check if a computer certificate is there or not. Its a Wireless certificate to be specific.

Here is my code so far:

```
public void Analyser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates
        .Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "MyCertName", false);
}
```

Comment: Just taking a stab in the dark but couldn't you check and see if the col variable is null?

Answer (score 7):

This works:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, 
    "subjectName", 
    false);

if (certificates != null && certificates.Count > 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Certificate already exists");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The collection itself will be empty if the certificate was not found.

```
if(col.Count > 0) {
    // Cert found!
}
```

My method for obtaining our certificate:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
X509Certificate2 cert = default(cert);
try
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "find.my@cert.com", true);
    cert = collection[0];
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("Error while fetching certificate. Please check that the application user can access the store.\r\n" + e.Message);
}
finally
{
    store.Close();
}
```